# Setting up Copper CoAP Plugin for Firefox

Tags: firefox, coap

I'm trying to set up Copper on Firefox version 53.0.3 and I am aware that the extension/plugin is not available anymore for Firefox 56+. I followed the instructions on how to set it up (https://github.com/mkovatsc/Copper) and I'm stuck at creating the text file copper@vs.inf.ethz.ch in the extensions directory of my Firefox profile. I noticed that the extensions file should be an .xpi file. Do I need to write anything in the file like any other Firefox extension to make it work?. I'm pretty new at this and I could use some help from more experienced people. Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Try in chrome browser!It perfectly works for me.Firefox in Cu4r is a little complex.